# How to destroy the response before each http request using angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to clear my http response before each request sending to API.

```
My Http request:
  $http(
            {
                method: 'GET',
                url: URI,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                async: false
            }).success(function (data) {
                $('#processing').hide();

                $scope.items  = JSON.parse( angular.toJson(data));

                $scope.header =  $scope.items[0];
```

Could you please help me ,so that each time I will get new response?

Thanks

Comment: Every request is asynchronous request.. U can't clear the response before calling.. Put your next request in your complete function

Answer (score 0):

The response is probably cached by browser or something between your browser and server. 
You can either try to prevent caching by adding header which tells the browser not the cache given response

Or

you can append unique timestamp to the URL, like this

```
var no_cache_url = URL + new Date().getTime()
```

If you are using some query string in your url then the code is slightly more complicated, but you will figure that out.